# How to use d3.js to select an svg element and modify its attr?

Tags: d3.js

I'm a bit new to `d3.js` and I guess my question is not about any detailed code or data.

here it is:

```
function selectNodesWithProperty(container, key, value){
  var nodes = d3.selectAll(container).select(function(d, i) { 
    if (value == d[key]) {
      console.log(this); // this works correctly, the element is the one I want.
      this.attr('fill', 'red') 
    }
  });
}
selectNodesWithProperty(".selector", "id", "Blue");
```

I have two questions:

1. Is my way the proper way to select the element by data?
2. Is there any way that I can use d3's `attr` for the element?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to use [`selection.filter()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter) to get a subset of the selection containing all the nodes for which the filter is true. You can then use [`.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) on the selection returned by `.filter()` to apply changes to the attribute values of the new subset only.

```
function selectNodesWithProperty(container, key, value){
  d3.selectAll(container)
    .filter(d => value === d[key]) 
    .attr('fill', 'red') 
}
```